# Reference class type in dataclass definition

Tags: python, typing, python-dataclasses

Is it possible to reference the class currently being defined within the class definition?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Branch:
    tree: List[Branch]
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'Branch' is not defined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't finished defining `Branch` when you use it in your type hint and so the interpreter throws a NameError. It's the same reason this doesn't work:

```
class T:
   t = T()
```

You can delay evaluation by putting it in a string literal like so

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Branch:
    tree: List['Branch']
```

---

This was actually decided to be a bad decision in the original spec and [there are moves](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) to revert it. If you are using Python 3.7 (which I'm guessing you are since you are using `dataclasses`, although it is available on PyPI), you can put `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of your file to enable this new behaviour and your original code will work.